# slug error still comes after deleting django model

Tags: django, django-models, slug, django-migrations

I had created a model in `models.py` but forgot to add the slug field. The error `Key (slug)=() is duplicated` comes after `python manage.py migrate` command. So I deleted my model and the slug field and again run the migration command but still the `python manage.py migrate` command shows the same error. I cannot delete my whole database because I have data stored in other models also. 
Here is the output of `python manage.py showmigrations`
 command:

```
admin
[X] 0001_initial
[X] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
[X] 0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices
auth
[X] 0001_initial
[X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
[X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
[X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
[X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
[X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
[X] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
[X] 0008_alter_user_username_max_length
[X] 0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length
contenttypes
[X] 0001_initial
[X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
schooldekho
[X] 0001_initial
[X] 0002_auto_20181114_0012
[X] 0003_auto_20181114_0041
[X] 0004_auto_20181114_0043
[X] 0005_auto_20181116_1759
[X] 0006_school
[ ] 0007_school_slug
[ ] 0008_auto_20181116_2259
[ ] 0009_auto_20181116_2300
[ ] 0010_auto_20181116_2304
[ ] 0011_remove_school_slug
[ ] 0012_auto_20181118_2238
sessions
[X] 0001_initial
```

All I want is to run the migration successfully without any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a migration which will add the `SlugField` with `null=True` and with no `default` specified for `default=None`. Then create an empty migration, and modify it so that you will populate the slug field that was added in the previous migration. Then you can create a new migration that will remove the `null=True` constraint.

Short version:

1. Create nullable column
2. Populate all null values for column via data migration.
3. Make column not-nullable.